# How init position from 1 not 0 in java

Tags: java, android

I build an app, which shows markers on a map, how can I do so that the following code, the initial position is not 0, but 1.

The problem that I have, is that the `array_ruta`, I send it to a spinner, but in the spinner the initial position is **SELECT OPTION**, and the items must start at position 1, but the `array_ruta` is arriving in the position 0, and 0 is empty, I need that arrive in position 1, that is where begining the options of spinner

This is String for send from position 1-2-3 ..., not 0-1-2

```
private String getemployeeName(int position){
        String name="";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            //Fetching name from that object
            name = json.getString( array_ruta);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java all arrays start at 0, you would have to make position 0 null and when you call the array start at position 1.